# Rebounding Object Off Wall / Reversing Velocity in Java

Tags: java

I have an object with velocity of -5 going towards a wall. When it hits the wall, I want it to get a velocity of 5, thus reversing directions and rebounding. However, when I run it, it is not working. I've used several variations, I guess I am making a syntactical error.

```
public void action(int t) {
   setVY(-5);              //works - no surprises sets velocity to -5
      .
      .

if(getY() <= 0 ) {


       setVY(5);          //THIS METHOD DOESN'T WORK

       setVX(5);           // works no surprises , ball goes right

       hooks.setMessage("hits wall", 25);   //no surprises
        }

}
```

This does compile and run with no errors. The object now goes north and then veers north/east at 45 degrees.

Comment: Which of the 3 statements don't work? If you print out vy after vy=getVY(); and vy = -vy;, what do you get? And if you just manually call setVY(5), does that work?

Comment: You haven't provided enough code for anyone to help you, but I'm concerned with the magic "5" in if (getY() == 5).

Comment: You should also alter the position of your object the moment it goes out of game region.

Comment: As in preventing it from leaving? Thanks, I have tried that, to no avail

Answer (score 1):

i'm sorry I can't comment on your question therefor I use the answering facility. Could you be more specific as to what is not working. Is you value for vy wrong or is the setter setVY not setting the right value to your object? Or is something different not working?

as Gilbert above mentioned: Why do you compare y to 5? Couldn't there be situations where y never is exactly 5 something a little bit smaller or larger than 5. E.g. the object is already a small fraction "inside" the wall and you still want the object to change direction and rebound...

Bye,
Markus

Answer (score 1):

This works. Although it does perhaps not work as you expect. Are you remembering to add the velocity to the position, before checking the position again? If not, getY() will still return 5, and it will flip the sign of yv again (so it's back the way it was). You can write a small unit test which confirms that this works.

Since your example is not functional, it's hard to say exactly what's wrong, but if you feed the algorithm with the correct data, it will flip the sign of the y velocity.